# CDT : IASTBinaryExpression calculating the value

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I'm working on the development of the eclipse plugin based on CDT.

The plugin parses the C++ code and generates another C++ code based on the data from parsed code.

Suppose the original code is

```
enum SOMEENUM
{
  ONE                         = 1 <<  1  //  Bit   2             2
 ,TWO                         = 1 <<  2  //  Bit   3             4
 ,THREE                       = 1 <<  3  //  Bit   4             8
 ,FOUR                        = 1 <<  4  //  Bit   5            16
}
```

CDT recognizes the `1 <<  1`, `1 <<  2`, etc as `IASTBinaryExpression`.

**Question** : Does anybody know how is it possible to evaluate the value of each binary expression by means of CDT ?

Otherwise the only option remain the calculation by manual parsing of all operands.